# Connecting to postgresql through python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

As part of a larger project I'm trying to automate the creation of a PostgreSQL database and user as well as assign them a role running on Ubuntu. I have figured out  how to create a database and that psycopg2 is what i want to connect to it with  the issue is i cannot seem to find a way to connect to the database. If i use the commands

```
sudo -u postgres bash
psql testBase
```

I can access the database and set up the rule manually.  and from what i can tell there is no default password for the postgres user it uses some other type of authentification

```
os.system("sudo -H -u postgres bash -c 'createuser -DRS test2'")
os.system("sudo -H -u postgres bash -c 'createdb -O test2 testBase'")
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="testBase", user="test2", host="127.0.0.1")
```

creates the database and user but then i get the result

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 7, in <module>
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database="testBase", user="test2", host="127.0.0.1")
  File "/home/openvas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Comment: What do you want to do?  Do you want to use password authentication for this new user you created, or some other method?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following scenario:

1. Create database and role by hand (one time job)
2. Now use `psql_dumpall` to create "template" (one time job as well)
3. During your automation operations replace database creation with loading your dump file (over and over again with each new instance)

Since `psql_dumpall` dumps entire db instance then after loading dump you have roles to login with as well. Just add password change in your code and should be good to go.

Comment: Would the psql_dumpall include extensions aswell ans roles and users

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql provides passwordless connections over a Unix domain socket.  To obtain this behaviour using psycopg2, omit the `host` argument from the call to the connection constructor.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="testBase", user="test2")
```

If you *want* to use a connection secured by a password you will need to edit the `pg_hba.conf` file to add a line like this (select for IPv4/IPv6):

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# IPv4 local connections:
host    testBase        test2             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    testBase        test2             ::1/128                 md5
```

The `pg_hba.conf` file includes descriptions of each column.

If you want to connect from a different host, you will need to set

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

in the `postgresql.conf` file (and make any necessary changes to your firewall).

Restart / reload the postgresql service after changing configuration files.

As jjanes' comment indicates, it seems `pg_hba.conf` has already been configured for password authentication, so you need decide whether to connect passwordlessly over the unix socket or using a user/password combination over tcp/ip.

Comment: The pg_hba must already be configured or he wouldn't be getting that error message.

Comment: I'm wondering if ubuntu automatically sets up for md5. Because that error has happened for me with a clean install of ubuntu on a virtual machine. I originally tried without the host and got the same error.

Comment: I don't have an Ubuntu setup to hand, but on my OpenSuse machine, (local)host IPv4/6 is set up for  method IDENT, which is password authentication but with the password passed as clear text rather than hashed.  But even if password auth is enabled, you still need a postgres user with a password set to connect.